# ng-bootstrap dropup and dropdown placement in the same page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

Is there any option in ng-bootstrap for dropdown and dropup on the same page?

 
I have tried the below code as given in the [documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples#config) of ng-bootstrap. but it is a Global configuration of dropdowns. **I want dropdown and dropup on the same page**. I'm working with Angular 8.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbDropdownConfig} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-dropdown-config',
  templateUrl: './dropdown-config.html',
  providers: [NgbDropdownConfig] // add NgbDropdownConfig to the component providers
})
export class NgbdDropdownConfig {
  constructor(config: NgbDropdownConfig) {
    // customize default values of dropdowns used by this component tree
    config.placement = 'top-left';
    config.autoClose = false;
  }
}
```

```
<div ngbDropdown>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="dropDownMenuButton" ngbDropdownToggle>
      Dropup Menu
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu tx-13" ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropDownMenuButton">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dropup" ngbDropdown>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="dropupMenuButton" ngbDropdownToggle>
      Dropup Menu
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu tx-13" ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropupMenuButton">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [API](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/api).
You can also set a placement directly to `NgbDropdown` directive, like so

```
<div class="dropup" ngbDropdown placement="top-left">
...
</div>
```

And here is a [nice guide](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/positioning) for NgBootstrap positioning, there are more example you can find.